# Remove @hotmail.com from string

Tags: php

I was wondering how you would remove `@hotmail.com` from `example@hotmail.com`?

Thanks

Comment: I havent, I was trying to remove replace the @ with a space and then remove everything after the first wrod in the string. But im guessing theres an easier way?

Comment: What @AJ is getting at: you'll get better answers when you can show that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself, first. Just FYI. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function remove_domain($email) {
  $v = explode("@", $email);
  return $v[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Preg way to do it:

This will remove **any domain name** from any email:

```
// Sample email address for testing:
$email = "example@anything.tld";
// Now let's remove @anything.tld:
$email = preg_replace('/@.+/','',$email);
// And then echo results out to see what we got:
echo $email;
```

So most **important thing here is** this line, focus on it:

```
echo preg_replace('/@.+/', '', 'example@deleteme.com');
```

It removes, using regular expression matching, anything that starts with `@` followed by at least one any character. After that it prints out result. So all can be done with single line and every domain is supported (throwed away) equally.

After that `$email` contains just `"example"` with `@anything.tld` removed.

This way `$email` can be `"my.mail.box@hotmail.com"`, `"somebody@mail.ex-ample.com"` or anything you can imagine.

You can read more about regular expressions here: [function.preg-replace.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), here: [pcre.org](http://www.pcre.org/) or here: [wikipedia/Regular_expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

### If you want to go with str_replace:

```php
$domain = 'gmail.com';
$email = str_replace('@'.$domain, '', $email);
```

PHP manual page here: [function.str-replace.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str_replace`,

```
$email = 'example@hotmail.com';
echo str_replace('@hotmail.com', '', $email); // example
```

Check the docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: If user1056534 will want to remove "@gmail.com" instead of "hotmail.com", should he create another question on this site to solve his problem?

Comment: He should use his head and try and solve it considering he knows how to use `str_replace` now.

Comment: Can you tell me how to remove an arbitrary domain from email using str_replace?

Comment: For one the person asking this question didn't ask how to remove an arbitrary domain using `str_replace` and two if you don't know yourself then ask a question on stack overflow yourself and not in the comments of my answers.

Comment: @Riateche I can.. `$domain = 'gmail.com';` then `$email = str_replace('@'.$domain, '', $email);` ... was that so hard?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best way for doing this but you could try something like:

```
$string = "email@hotmail.com";
$new_string = explode("@", $string);
print $new_string[0] // will print 'email'
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Or simply with [strstr(string $haystack ,mixed $needle [,bool $before_needle = false ])](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php), 
then you dont need to check for specific domain:

```
$email = 'blabla@hotmail.com';

echo strstr($email, '@', true);
```